# How To Get C# to Point to an Absolute Path

Tags: c#, file-upload, filepath

I'm getting the error "SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and and the path 'images309.jpg' is not rooted." This is for an admin page that has an upload button for images.
Right away I can tell that the "/" is not being placed in to the path as it is being built/constructed. However, I'm not certain HOW to do this with the C# code that I'm presented with. I've googled to no avail, and have did much musical chairs with the code. I even took a known working admin page with an upload of image feature and copied its line where the upload occurs, but I'm simply having trouble figuring out the syntax.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple with the path, but perhaps it is a bit different with C# (Which I am days new to).

the code:

```
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE [doctor_bios] SET [bio] = @bio, [phone] = @phone, [keywords] = @keywords, [email] = @email";
    if (NewPicture.HasFile)
    {
        if (!Picture.ImageUrl.Equals(string.Empty)) { File.Delete(@"images" + Picture.ImageUrl); }
        NewPicture.SaveAs(@"images" + NewPicture.FileName);
        command.CommandText += ", [pictureURL] = @pictureURL";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pictureURL", "xxx/xxx/images/docimg/" + NewPicture.FileName));
    }
    command.CommandText += " WHERE [doctor_id] = @id";
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bio", Bio.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phone", Phone.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", Email.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@keywords", Keywords.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", Request.QueryString["id"]));
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    phnDB.Close();

}
```

}

Comment: Educated guess: Just add a slash. `NewPicture.SaveAs(@"/images" + NewPicture.FileName)` to save to the "current" directory.

Comment: I did that but to no avail. That was my first try of a solution

Comment: What is the type of `NewPicture`? I can't figure out what classes you are using. Do you not have a full path available? You can try `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"images" + NewPicture.FileName)` to get a full path to the current directory.

Comment: it is a .jpg
I have full path yes, I've entered it in exactly as it is in a known working file that is also an admin page with this code:
PictureFile.SaveAs(@"c:\xxx\xxx\images\docimg" + PictureFile.FileName);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pictureURL", "images/" + PictureFile.FileName));

but when I do that, I get an error. It was a different error but when I try to replicate the error, I'm now getting a  security error. When I revert to see if access has been denied to me, I now get the original error that I'm posting about.